# psql: FATAL: role "test" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.6

I am new to postgres and facing difficulty in connecting to DB after server reboot. I have created a database pgdb under an OS user test. 
After Server restarted, I restarted pgsql by issuing the 
command

```
service postgresql-9.6 start
```

> Starting postgresql-9.6 service:                      [ OK  ]

If i just issue psql, I am taken to psql prompt but the data path here is different than what I have set previously. When I try to connect to pgdb as postgres user, I get the error:

> psql: FATAL:  database "pgdb" does not exist

When I try to connect as Test user:

```
psql -d pgdb
```

> psql: FATAL:  role "test" does not exist

Please suggest

Comment: Why do You use few version tags? How is Your problem specific only to particular version?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. There is no **database** user named `test`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the database you created under the OS user test is under a **different** instance of Postgres than the instance that was instantiated by `service postgresql-9.6 start`.  The two instances could be (or could have been, before the server restarted) running under different ports (eg, 5432 and 5433).

Or, since you have this tagged as both postgres-9.4 and postgres-9.6, you need to be aware that they are distinct from each other.  *Any database you created under Postgres 9.4 should not be expected to exist under Postgres 9.6*.  If you created the `pgdb` database under 9.4, but after the reboot, began running 9.6, you generally would need to migrate the db (the procedure for which is beyond the scope of this question).  Likewise, a user created under 9.4 would not automatically exist under 9.6.